# Will Sasuke's Kirin work against Obito?

Tags: naruto

In the last chapters, they figure out that only natural energy will work against obito.

Sasuke's Kirin is made out of natural lightning and he only needs a small amount of chakra to control and direct it to his target.

So I wonder if Kirin will work like a sage jutsu against Obito?

Comment: Even if there's traces of chakra lightning in kirin, there will still be massive amounts of natural lightning, assuming sasuke will be able to set it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have any proof for the moment that it would work or not against Obito.

But I would say that *Kirin* wouldn't work. It's categorized as a *Raiton jutsu*. So it's still *ninjutsu* and Obito should not be damaged.

Also, to use this *jutsu*, Sasuke needs to use a *Katon jutsu* to create the clouds. So, when the clouds are charged with thunders, it may still have some energy of the previous, meaning that it's not really natural lightning.

Comment: Yeah it's safe to say that ninjutsu is out of the question at this poing